# MDX for Percent of Total for a subset of a Hierarchy

Tags: mdx

i have some what of a basic mdx question. I need to caclulate the percent of total in a hierarchy and i'm having problems when i want a result set that doesn't include the complete hierarchy.

i have a fairly basic dimension that looks like

```
Groups
    Group A
        Item 1
        Item 2
        Item 3
    Group B
        Item 4
        Item 5
    Group C
        Item 6
        Item 7
        Item 8
```

I'm using a calculated measure i found in my readings that works well if I'm looking at the complete hierarchy, but falls apart when i want to look at a subset.

For example,

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Percent] AS iif([Measures].[Result Count] = 0,
NULL,
IIF(isempty( ([Measures].[Result Count], Axis(1)(0)( Axis(1)(0).Count - 1).Dimension.CurrentMember.Parent )),1,
[Measures].[Result Count] / ( [Measures].[Result Count], Axis(1)(0)( Axis(1)(0).Count - 1 ).Dimension.CurrentMember.Parent ))), FORMAT_STRING ="#,##0.00 %;-#,##0.00 %"
SELECT
   { [Measures].[Result Count],[Measures].[Percent] } ON COLUMNS,
   { [Groups].[Group Participation]} ON ROWS
FROM [Cube]
```

I get the following:

```
        Result Count    Percent
Group A     1541            11.92 %
Group B     2300            17.79 %
Group C     9086            70.29 %
```

Which works great. However, if i only want Group B & Group C:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Percent] AS iif([Measures].[Result Count] = 0,
NULL,
IIF(isempty( ([Measures].[Result Count], Axis(1)(0)( Axis(1)(0).Count - 1 ).Dimension.CurrentMember.Parent )),1,
[Measures].[Result Count] / ( [Measures].[Result Count], Axis(1)(0)( Axis(1)(0).Count - 1 ).Dimension.CurrentMember.Parent ))), FORMAT_STRING ="#,##0.00 %;-#,##0.00 %"
SELECT
   { [Measures].[Result Count],[Measures].[Percent] } ON COLUMNS,
   { [Groups].[Group Participation].&[1],[Groups].[Group Participation].&[2]} ON ROWS
FROM [Cube]
```

I get the following:

```
        Result Count    Percent
Group B     2300            17.79 %
Group C     9086            70.29 %
```

I want

```
        Result Count    Percent
Group B     2300            20.20 %
Group C     9086            79.79 %
```

Basically, i need the sum of the percent to add up to 100.

I also need this to work at the leaf nodes. when i change the statment to only return Item 4, Item 5, Item 6

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Percent] AS iif([Measures].[Result Count] = 0,
NULL,
IIF(isempty( ([Measures].[Result Count], Axis(1)(0)( Axis(1)(0).Count - 1 ).Dimension.CurrentMember.Parent )),1,
[Measures].[Result Count] / ( [Measures].[Result Count], Axis(1)(0)( Axis(1)(0).Count - 1 ).Dimension.CurrentMember.Parent ))), FORMAT_STRING ="#,##0.00 %;-#,##0.00 %"
SELECT
   { [Measures].[Result Count],[Measures].[Percent] } ON COLUMNS,
   { [Groups].[Group].&[4],[Groups].[Group].&[5],[Groups].[Group].&[6]} ON ROWS
FROM [Cube]
```

I get the following:

```
    Result Count    Percent 
Item 4  103             4.48 %
Item 5  12              0.52 %
Item 6  455             19.78 %
```

I want to get

```
    Result Count    Percent 
Item 4  103             18.07 %
Item 5  12              2.10 %
Item 6  455             79.82 %
```

I feel like i'm missing something very basic. What am i doing wrong in my calculated measure?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem by specifying dimension members (leaf nodes) of the filtered view in the calculated percentage member, instead of using `axis()`. In the web app I'm working on, MDX is generated on the fly so it was easy to implement it.

In the example above, this would mean that for leaf nodes (examples that returns items 4,5 and 6) it should look like this:

```
[Measures].[Result Count] / SUM( { [Groups].[Group].&[4],
      [Groups].[Group].&[5],[Groups].[Group].&[6]}, [Measures].[Result Count] )
```

instead of:

```
[Measures].[Result Count] / ( [Measures].[Result Count], 
    Axis(1)(0)( Axis(1)(0).Count - 1 ).Dimension.CurrentMember.Parent )
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not use anymore the 'natural' hierarchy of a dimension (parent) to get the total but use a sum over the axis in your calculated members.

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Percent] AS [Measures].[Result Count] / Sum( Axis(1), [Measures].[Result Count])  , FORMAT_STRING = 'percent'
```

That should get your 'visual' percentage.

Comment: the formula didn't work, it returns the percent of the item of the total dimension, and not the filtered view.

Comment: This worked well for me within the MDX query I had.  Trying to make it a calculated field in the cube was OK in MDX queries but the calculation wasn't correct when used in an Excel Pivot table.  It seems like the All member gets included in that context and makes all the percentages roughly half what they should.